# What is second person?

Tags: grammar

I understand that first person is written from my perspective, so I would be using the words "I, me, my, mine" a lot.

I also understand that third person is written from no particular perspective, but is instead an overview. I would be using words similar to "he did this, she did that, he said to her", etc.

What is second person? I seem to have never heard of it despite taking English at school.

Comment: Hello, Matthias. The principal usage of 'first person' etc is in grammar; in 'first-person narrative' it is derivative. What research have you done on this? The grammar involved is very basic, and you should know about it (and mention it in a question about possible other usages).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I didn't know what to tag this with. Can you suggest a more appropriate tag?

Comment: Can you address my concern first? Wikipedia has articles on ['first person' in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_person) and ['grammatical person'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_person); [Nordquist](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/First-Person-Pronouns.htm) is a great resource (check the links he provides too!)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I have done very little research on this, thank you for those articles. I'm sorry about the previous response, I thought you were referring to the 'grammar' tag. What did you mean by derivative and first person narrative?

Comment: Notice that oerkelens' first sentence below correctly addresses the issue of grammatical person. Only then does he go on to talk about 'stories [etc] written in the second person', ie 'second person narrative'. Your query 'What is second person? I seem to have never heard of it despite taking English at school' indicates that you **first** need to master the grammar terminology involved before you can sensibly think about 'second person narrative'.

Comment: I don't understand why this needs to be a question. When your mom gives you direction, she would tell you, "you will come to junction, then you should turn left, and then you would pass a cake shop, and then you would see a hotel, .. you ... you ... you"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second person is *you* (singular and plural), as in, *the party that is being addressed by the speaker*.

A *story* in the second person is rare, because I would tell *you* what is happening to *you*. Normally, *you* would know that better than I would, and *you* should be telling me the story.

However, I remember stories in children's books that went something like:

> Imagine you are in a dark room, you can't see anything. Carefully, using your hands, you feel your way around, until you stumble on a doorknob. Just as you want to turn the know, it moves by itself! You scream, your heart racing in your throat... "Who is there?" you shout. There is only silence...

Also, in manuals or recipes and the like, the second person is sometimes used:

> After you take the duck out of the oven, you let it rest for a while. While you cut the vegetables, you make sure the duck doesn't move.

Comment: I was about to give the usual rant 'This website isn't for such basic ...'. Then I got past the first sentence. // If I remember correctly, when Agatha Christie was running out of twists, she ended a whodunnit in the second person, proving that it had to be the reader who dunnit.